# Parallel iteration for nested tuples in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I was wondering if something akin to:

```
x,y = (1,2),'a'
```

would be possible in a for loop, like:

```
my_tuple = ((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
your_tuple = ('a','b','c')

for x,y in my_tuple, your_tuple:
    ...
```

At the moment I can't even figure out how to do it with 3 variables.

Comment: one word: `zip`.

Comment: Take a look at [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Okay, that was easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: It's often easier than you think in Python :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), my dear friend!
 Here is the code:

```
my_tuple = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))
your_tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c')

for x, y in zip(my_tuple, your_tuple):
    print(x, y)
```